# If I graft two trees together while young, will they grow as one plant?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

If I were to graft two apple saplings together --  by bending the tops toward each other and lashing them together --  will the plants grow as one and benefit from one another, or will they be fighting each other for root space and light? If they would grow with each other, then I could theoretically grow a line of closely spaced fruit trees to any length, and they would be strengthened by each other in bad conditions.

Comment: check [this](http://www.treeof40fruit.com/) out

Comment: That is not grafting, if they are not sharing vascular tissue all you are doing is making a weird topiary. apple trees are very often grafted (to prevent inbreeding infertility) so if you want to do it you can find plenty of information.

Comment: @John: That's really not why apples (and many other fruit trees) are grafted.  Grafting allows particular varieties to be propagated quickly (varieties don't come true from seed), you can select rootstocks to control height (dwarfing or semi-dwarfing), add hardiness & disease resistance, &c.  You can even graft several varieties of a fruit on a single tree.  See any commercial fruit tree catalog.

Comment: @jamesqf I was talking about apples specifically not all fruit. Apple often have a singe branch from a crabapple grafted on to the tree because apples will not fruit with pollen from a similar apple (a gala apple tree will not fertilize with pollen from another gala apple tree for instance) by grafting a very different breed it insures that each tree will fruit as much as it can.

Comment: @John that is uncommon, and in commercial orchards it’s pretty much unheard of. Grafting is basically used to propagate cultivars, which don’t come true from seed,   As well as get consistent anchorage, mature height, disease resistance, etc.. Source: worked in nursery for many years, grafting trees, and also had a personal orchard, and maintained several others for many years.

Comment: @John: OK, makes more sense when you explain it, though I've never seen or read about it before.  But I tend to prefer heirloom varieties, where it's not so much of a problem.  Or if it is, the nursery says "plant two varieties" :-)  But grafting onto various rootstocks is absolutely the norm.

Comment: It is common is apple trees sold for domestic use and I am well aware of the many uses for grafting, I was giving an example a layman might be familiar with. Apple don't come true from seeds for the same reason the grafting I mentioned is done they exhibit strong inbreeding infertility so fruiting apples need constant outbreeding. Cultivars can be bred true from seeds however it is extremely time consuming (15 years +) and very labor intensive, grafting is just faster. Legacy nurseryman myself ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of answers to this question.  Especially where trees are concerned, you can graft [two or more trees onto the same rootstock, or even a single limb into a tree](http://inventorspot.com/articles/lemon_tree_japan_bears_eleven_ki_9572).

But if the graft takes, it won't behave too much more differently than just more branches of the same tree.  Structurally intertwining them will not be different than if you had just taken a single tree's branches to support each other.  The graft will usually only have a single set of roots, from the host tree.  They will not compete.  The tendency will be for the branches to grow apart so that they can independently get their own light.  This is very much like any other single tree.  Not sure about fusing two halves of a tree together - exposing the roots would tend to kill the tree or unsettle it.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is not grafting it is called [inosculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inosculation) and can prodice some truly impressive results.
Inosculation can sometimes *lead* to natural grafting but it just as often does not. Apples are a good candidate for this to form grafting but it is not guaranteed. More importantly said trees are often competing for light so you end up having to plant more trees for the same amount of fruit, plus it is extremely time consuming.

As for strengthening that depends a lot on what you call strengthening, they may help each other structurally but joining becomes a liability for say something like drought conditions because you have a smaller root mass per tree.